# Display images from custom post type gallery with ACF on another custom single page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

With this code, all the images on the relationship shows, but post object keeps repeating many times... what's wrong with this code and what's a better way of implementing it?

It's using a gallery as custom post type object, assigned to this custom post type single page.

the page is looking right but, if I debug, the `<?php foreach( $images as $image_id ): ?>`
loop is repeating a lot more than it should some how.

Any ideas on what's the problem here?

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <div class="employee-page">
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="employee-gallery">
                        <div class="row">

                            <?php $posts = get_field('employee_gallery'); ?>
                            <?php if( $posts ): ?>
                            <?php foreach( $posts as $post):  ?>
                            <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

                            <?php 
                                $images = get_field('gallery');
                                $size = 'large';  
                                if( $images ): ?>

                            <?php foreach( $images as $image_id ): ?>

                            <div class="column col-lg-2 col-md-4  col-xs-12">
                                <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'full' ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, $size ); ?></a>
                            </div>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </main>
</div>

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: Don't beat me up too much, this is just a thought, and may be completely off base since HTML isn't my bag...  The thought is maybe get rid of all those open and close tags for php.  Seems like a single open at the beginning of your php and a single close tag would be sufficient?

Comment: So the employee_gallery is a relationship field where you select post to include from you custom post type is that correct? And the gallery is an acf gallery field you use in each custom post single?

Comment: I have 2 custom post types, gallery and employees. When i add an employee I assign/select a gallery from all galleries created under gallery. I've used acf to create the field and relationship